# How to get the url parameter?

Tags: node.js, express

I am very new to Express, I want to parse the url parameter. My code as below:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var aCustomerIdValue = req.param.aa;
  console.log('In / Function be called: %s',aCustomerIdValue);
  res.redirect('/checkouts/new');
});
```

But the console show "undefine". Any clue for it?
My express is 4.0.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `req.param` is wrong, it's `req.params`. But what you're actually looking for is [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Parameter types

#### req.params

It should be **`req.params.aa`** instead of `req.param.aa` - see:

- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

but it would work only for `":aa"` parameters in the **path** of routes like `router.get('/:aa', ...)` - it would save `XXX` from request to **`GET /XXX`** in **`req.params.aa`**

#### req.query

For query parameters (most likely for **GET** requests) use `req.query` - see:

- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

It will save `XXX` from request to **`GET /?aa=XXX`** in **`req.query.aa`**

#### req.body

For the parameters passed in the request body use `req.body` - see:

- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

It will save `aa` parameters passed in the **body** of the request (most likely for **`POST`** requests) in **`req.body.aa`**

#### req.param()

There is also `req.param('name')` for either one of those, searched in order of:

1. `req.params`
2. `req.body`
3. `req.query`

but it is **deprecated** - thanks to  Ben Fortune for pointing it out in the comment - see: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param

### Your example

Try:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var aCustomerIdValue = req.query.aa;
  console.log('In / Function be called: %s', aCustomerIdValue);
  res.redirect('/checkouts/new');
});
```

if the parameter is passed in the query string, or:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var aCustomerIdValue = req.body.aa;
  console.log('In / Function be called: %s', aCustomerIdValue);
  res.redirect('/checkouts/new');
});
```

if the parameter is passed in the request body.

Comment: `param` is deprecated.

Comment: @BenFortune thanks for pointing it out, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, req.query.aa; is the key point, I shouldn't use req.params.aa, because my url link looks like: localhost:3000/?aa=11234

Comment: @noellee That's good to hear. If it solved your problem you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that this question can be marked as answered for others who search the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put `body-parser` code in your `server` file above all the `routes`

Like this

```
var app=repress();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
```

And if you are passing `query` parameters then get it on server side by

> req.query

And if you are passing `parameters` then get it server side by

> req.params